# When does one divide by the meta_batch_size for MAML during meta-learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I was going through the maml example in the higher library but it seems to me they are forgetting to divide by the `meta_batch_size`, they have:

```
qry_loss.backward()
```

where they should have

```
meta_batch_size = qry_loss.size(0)
(qry_loss/meta_batch_size).backward()
```

is this correct? should they be dividing by the `meta_batch_size`?

references:

- full code example working on omniglot: https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/blob/master/examples/maml-omniglot.py
- crossposted: https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/issues/104
- cross: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/when-does-one-divide-by-the-meta-batch-size-for-maml-during-meta-learning/114625

---

if you don't have the grads field being populated see this: https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/issues/129

Comment: if you don't have the grads field being populated see this: https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/issues/129

Answer (score 0):

They are "equivalent" if you choose the right step size.

The 1st one has this update rule:

```
w := w - eta1 (E[l] +- std[l]/sqr{B})
```

2nd:

```
w := w - eta2 (B E[l] +- sqrt{B} std[l])
```

they are the same if `eta2 = eta1/B`. Assuming you can substitute the gradient more or less with mean +- std (not quite but thats fine, it's to get a feeling if they more or less are distributed the same, similarly enough).

Comment: if you don't have the grads field being populated see this: https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/issues/129